# Should I match the curly brace usage of the previous author?

Tags: standards, coding-style

When working on code from multiple authors, I often encounter the issue of curly-brace preference (same line vs new line).  Is it good/bad practice or even a non-issue when it comes to matching the existing style vs using your own preference?

Does the situation change if you are adding new code to a Class vs modifying existing code?  Finally, if style should be matched, how far should the match propagate? i.e. the file, the class, subclasses etc.

Example:

```
if(this)
{
    doThat();
}
```

Vs.

```
if(this){
    doThat();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, inconsistently formatted code will be more difficult to read and understand than code formatted in a style other than your own.

When working on an open source project, it is considered polite to match the style in use. For code you won't be sharing, either follow the style or run all the existing code through a reformatter.

Answer (score 3):

It matters a great deal if a lot of code has been checked into a version control system.  There will be a lot of noisy change in the history for a mere brace style change.  I wouldn't do it for its own sake.  You're in Rome....

Answer (score 2):

If you will be sharing this, match his style for consistency. If not, do what you find comfortable. I personally prefer your style.

Answer (score 0):

Try to talk with your coworkers and decide on a consistent style. Once you do that, write all new code in that style and convert old code if necessary. This is an issue specific to the project and the people working on it.

On the rare occasion that you can't come to a consensus, I wouldn't worry too much; there are far too many bugs in the world for people to be spending their time moving braces around. :D

Comment: "This is an issue specific to the project" How? "Because we are doing embedded systems rather than GUI apps, it is important for us to use braces on their own lines"? :-)

Comment: @Odd specific to the project as in "specific to the people working on it". But I do hear using tabs instead of spaces reduces bugs by 20% for web-app development... :D

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter (code wise) where you place the curly braces, it is just a matter of preference. More experienced coders tend to put it on the same line, but I like to put it on the next line because it helps me see blocks of code easier. If you wish coding conventions to go as far as curly braces, then consult your team and choose one, but they'll probably laugh lol

Comment: Sigh. They won't laugh. They will argue strongly for the next week, losing all other team productivity.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that irks me more than perusing code and finding numerous mismatched styles sprinkled throughout.  If you are going to collaborate with someone on a program, than either explicit or implicit, standards should be used. Something as simple as a curly brace doesn't matter in the least, but when your project gets reviewed by management and you can't even get that one little thing matched up throughout it looks bad. Or if you are working on a personal project with friends and then decide to have others join, the project is going to start off looking unprofessional. I would say when working in a group like this, it is less about personal opinion, than it is about group standards.